# CSS opacity - can't cover the text of the div underneath

Tags: css, opacity

I have a div with some text in it and "on hover", I want to display another div with some other text.

The problem is that the text from the first div comes through to the second and everything seems mingled up. I would like the second div to completely cover the first one.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zPYV/)

HTML

```
<div class="outer_box">
        <div class="inner_box">
            Main</div>
            <span class="caption">Caption</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer_box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:orange;

}

.inner_box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;

}

.caption {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

    background:black;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
    opacity:0;
}

.outer_box:hover .caption{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: ok, I hate it when it happens, I figured it out as soon as I posted the question. I can add: .outer_box:hover .inner_box{opacity:0;} Still however, why doesn't the div on-top cover the one below?

Comment: On Stack Overflow you are encouraged to submit an answer on your own questions and accept those that answer if you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.inner_box:hover {
    opacity: 0.0;
}
```

Comment: 0.0 is a bit too precise don't ya think?  ;-)

Comment: @MicahDelaneBolen yes, but opacity values lying between 0.0 and 1.0, 0.0 make things more clear I believe. :)

Comment: Yeah, figured it out, but I'll accept your answer for firsts! Still, I find it a bit strange that text is not completely opaque..

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.outer_box:hover, .inner_box:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```

If you will notice, I made sure to include the .outer_box:hover selector in case your intention ever was to make the outer box significantly larger than the inner box.

More useful information about the behavior of the opacity property can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to style the text from the first div so that it disappears on hover:

```
.inner_box:hover .text {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```